# swfobject callback fails to load without alert in jquery code

Tags: jquery, callback, alert, swfobject

Trying to get below code to run without the alert("");
With the alert it works fine, without the alert it fails.

Anyone an idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {};
    var embedHandler = function (e){

    if(e.success){
      alert('without this it fails')
      var f = swfobject.getObjectById('gameplayer');
          f.tabIndex = 0;
          f.focus();
      } else {
        //failed
      }
    };

    swfobject.embedSWF("/assets/gameplayer2.swf", "gameplayer", "393", "400", "9.0.0", "flash/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, embedHandler );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the code works at all, regardless of the `alert` -- your `swfobject.getObjectById('record')` doesn't match the ID in your SWFObject embed statement (`"gameplayer"`).

They need to match. You can either change `swfobject.getObjectById('record')` to `swfobject.getObjectById('gameplayer')`, or change `var params = {};` to `var params = { id: 'record' };` to ensure the new `<object>` has the id `"record"`.

You can read more about the param options here: http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/advanced-options-with-dynamic-publishing/

**Updated answer for updated question**

It may be a timing issue; `e.success` only indicates that the `<object>` has been successfully written to the page, not that Flash Player has finished initializing and/or the SWF has finished loading.

Try polling the SWF for `PercentLoaded` to see if it has finished loading, then execute your code.

```
function swfLoadEvent(fn){
    //Ensure fn is a valid function
    if(typeof fn !== "function"){ return false; }
    //This timeout ensures we don't try to access PercentLoaded too soon
    var initialTimeout = setTimeout(function (){
        //Ensure Flash Player's PercentLoaded method is available and returns a value
        if(typeof e.ref.PercentLoaded !== "undefined" && e.ref.PercentLoaded()){
            //Set up a timer to periodically check value of PercentLoaded
            var loadCheckInterval = setInterval(function (){
                //Once value == 100 (fully loaded) we can do whatever we want
                if(e.ref.PercentLoaded() === 100){
                    //Execute function
                    fn();
                    //Clear timer
                    clearInterval(loadCheckInterval);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    }, 200);
}

//This function is invoked by SWFObject once the <object> has been created
var callback = function (e){

    //Only execute if SWFObject embed was successful
    if(!e.success || !e.ref){ return false; }

    swfLoadEvent(function(){

        //Put your code here
        alert("The SWF has finished loading!");

    });

};

swfobject.embedSWF("movie.swf", "flashcontent", "550", "400", "9", false, false, false, false, callback);
```

Code copied from http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/

Comment: Ok that was a typo my bad, problem persists though. I changed the example.